# Creating a trigger that replaces a null with a specific value after inserts

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

I'm Trying to Create a Trigger that will replace a Specific Value inserted into a specific Column with another Specific Value.

Ex. Every time a '1' is inserted, a '2' will take it's place after insert and Update.

This TRIGGER ends up updating every row under the column to '2' after a new insert rather than JUST the new row that was inserted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_MakeFlag
ON Production.Product
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
    BEGIN
    UPDATE Production.Product
    SET MakeFlag = '2'
    WHERE MakeFlag = '1'
END
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to post your schema. What is the primary key for the table?

Comment: The Primary Key for this table is ProductID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to learn about and use the inserted and deleted collections in the trigger. Your current trigger is doing exactly what you're telling it to... on every insert and update, set ALL MakeFlag values to 2 if they're equal to 1, in the entire table. Nowhere in there are you limiting things to "just the rows affected".

So you really need something more like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_MakeFlag
ON Production.Product
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
    BEGIN
    UPDATE p
       SET MakeFlag = '2'
      FROM Production.Product p
           INNER JOIN inserted i ON p.ProductID = i.ProductID
     WHERE MakeFlag = '1'
END
```

Here you're joining your table with the inserted collection (which are the rows being inserted, or the 'after update' values after an update), to only affect the specific rows, and not all rows.

Of course, there's still an issue here.  You have a trigger that fires after an update on a given table, which then updates that table... which sounds kind of recursive to me. Probably not the best idea.

You might want to look at creating two INSTEAD OF triggers, one for inserts, and one for updates, which basically does an INSERT or UPDATE of the inserted collection to the table, replacing the one column with 2 where it's 1 (using a CASE statement).

This would look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_MakeFlag
ON Production.Product
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Production.Product (ProductID, MakeFlag, column3, column4, etc...)
        SELECT ProductID,
               CASE WHEN i.MakeFlag = 1 THEN 2 ELSE i.MakeFlag END,
               column3,
               column4, 
               ...
          FROM inserted;
END
```

You would have to list out all the columns (put the real names in there in place of column3, column4, etc....) and make sure you select all the same columns in the same order in your SELECT FROM inserted.  The CASE statement does the magic of converting every 1 inserted into a 2, while leaving all other values alone.

You'd do something similar with an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger.

Just some ideas for you to ponder.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.